# How do I make a text align under a logo using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a subheading for a logo in my website. I am having trouble with aligning it under the logo. I have placed a `p` tag inside a `div` and tried to position the `div` but I am not sure how it works.

Here is a photo of what the website currently looks like.
[image]

below is the code for it.

HTML:

```html
<!--logo goes here-->
<div class="logo">
  <img class="img" src="photos/logo1.png" alt="the logo">
</div>

<div class="textbox">
  <p class="subtext"> We care about you </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `img` tags don't have closing tags...

Answer (score 2):

Put the text in the same `div` where the logo is:

```html
<div class="logo"> 
  <img class="img" src="photos/logo1.png" alt="the logo">
  <p class="subtext"> We care about you </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both  and

are block elements, by default those tags go to the new line.
So what was your intention, putting the subheading right under the logo?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.